# VBA/Excel error - Error in value when using StartsWith

Tags: excel, vba

The function below prints value South when I call =LRegionName(cell) from excel when the value of the cell is S. But when the value of the cell is N it gives Error in Value in excel. What am I missing?

```
Function LRegionName(LRegion)
If LRegion = "S" Then
   LRegionName = "South"
ElseIf LRegion.startsWith("N") Then
    LRegionName = "North"
ElseIf LRegion = "E" Then
   LRegionName = "East"
ElseIf LRegion = "W" Then
   LRegionName = "West"
Else
   LRegionName = "Dont know"
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
ElseIf LRegion.startsWith("N") Then
```

with:

```
ElseIf Left(LRegion,1) = "N"  Then
```

Comment: That works. Wondering why. Is startsWith() not a valid function in VBA. I found a few examples using startsWith() which is why I used it

Comment: It doesn't exist in vba AFAIK. Use LEFT generally.

Comment: @Don If the function does not exist, we must use whatever is **Left** .............I apologize  for the humor.

Comment: @Don, `StartsWith` is VB.Net, not VBA. `String`s don't have methods in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gary's Answer if you're matching just one letter.

If you want to match multiple letters at the beginning, you can use

```
ElseIf LRegion Like "N*" Then
```

Here, the "*" means that it can be anything after N.
Similarly if you type "No*", it means it can be anything after "Nor" or "Norman" or  "North"